# Border radius, background image, background gradient, and IE8, IE10

Tags: css, background-image, css3pie

I've got a div with border radius, background gradient, and background image working in FireFox, but not in IE8 or IE10. Gradient and background image work in IE8, but when I apply the border radius, the border disappears.

```
.add-to-carttest {
border: 1px solid #004f9e;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 50px;
width:100px;
height: 40px;
font-weight:bold;
background: url(https://www.storesmart.com/mm5/graphics/00000001/add-to-cart-plus.png) no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#e1f0ff), to(#73b9ff));
background: url(https://www.storesmart.com/mm5/graphics/00000001/add-to-cart-plus.png) no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(#e1f0ff, #73b9ff);
background: url(https://www.storesmart.com/mm5/graphics/00000001/add-to-cart-plus.png) no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(#e1f0ff, #73b9ff);
background: url(https://www.storesmart.com/mm5/graphics/00000001/add-to-cart-plus.png) no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(#e1f0ff, #73b9ff);
background: url(https://www.storesmart.com/mm5/graphics/00000001/add-to-cart-plus.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#e1f0ff, #73b9ff);
background: url(https://www.storesmart.com/mm5/graphics/00000001/add-to-cart-plus.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#e1f0ff, #73b9ff);
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
behavior: url(../../Graphics/PIE/PIE.htc);
position:relative;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="#e1f0ff", endColorstr="#73b9ff",GradientType=0 ), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="https://www.storesmart.com/mm5/graphics/00000001/add-to-cart-plus.png");}
```

Comment: Also, how do I integrate background image positioning into this? I inserted it between "no-repeat" and "-webkit etc" on all those lines, and it works in FF and IE10, but in IE8, the image isn't positioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

border-radius is not available in IE8

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/backgrounds-borders/

oops - just noticed your behavior entry...may want to double check your path

Ok here is what I've come up with:

**CSS:**

```
.common
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #004f9e;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    !behavior: url(../../Graphics/PIE/PIE.htc);
    position: relative;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.add-to-carttest
{
    background-image: url('https://www.storesmart.com/mm5/graphics/00000001/add-to-cart-plus.png');
    background-position:20px 20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    top:-6px;
    left:-51px;
}

.gradient
{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#e1f0ff, #73b9ff); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#e1f0ff), to(#73b9ff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e1f0ff, #73b9ff);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#e1f0ff, #73b9ff);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#e1f0ff, #73b9ff);
    background: linear-gradient( #e1f0ff, #73b9ff);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e1f0ff', endColorstr='#73b9ff',GradientType=0 );
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e1f0ff', endColorstr='#73b9ff',GradientType=0 )";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="common gradient">
    <div class="common add-to-carttest"></div>
</div>
```

It seems the gradient filter in IE8 overrides and hides or repositions the background image because it seems the gradient itself is rendered as an image.  So I broke apart the css and nested the divs. Then repositioned the inner div to overlay the outer.  That seems to work, not elegant, but compatible.

Also, positioning via "bottom left" syntax only seems to work in newer browsers so I positioned the background image by pixel position

Hope this helps

Comment: If I take out all of the "background: url" stuff, the radius works. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: for what it's worth, it's likely not you, but IE8 :) - still trying to find a solution tho

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should have probably said so from the beginning, but I'm trying to style a button. I don't think I can put a div in a button (input). But you have answered my question: I'm trying something too ambitious for IE. I should probably just integrate my little image and the gradient into one big background image, or just make the whole button an image. Thanks!

Comment: you can't put a div into a button...but you can add an onclick to a div